# The force of an electron on itself

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons

**EDIT:** In [section 28-4 of The Feynman Lectures on Physics, vol II](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_28.html#Ch28-S4), the author briefly discusses the problem of the force an electron exerts on itself. Roughly put, an electron moving with acceleration emits electromagnetic waves which then influence its own motion. In a special case of 1-dimensional motion a differential equation (28.9) for this force is stated without proof. The problem is that if the electron is considered to be a material point, at least one of the coefficients in the equation becomes infinite. It is also mentioned that this problem has been studied by many people, but it remains unsolved.

More quantitatively this problem has been discussed in Landau-Lifshitz, vol.2, $\S$ 75. Thus the equation of motion (75.9)  of an electron in electromagnetic field is
$$m\overset{\cdot}{\vec v}=e\vec E+\frac{e}{c}\vec v\times \vec H+\frac{2e^2}{3c^3}\overset{\cdot\cdot}{\vec v},$$
under the assumptions that $v\ll c$ and the third term in the right hand side is much less that the first and the second ones. Note that the sum of the first two terms is the usual Lorentz force.

> I am wondering if the third term can actually be measured in experiments with electrons, or so far it represents purely theoretical interest.

Comment: I don't remember whether [*Conservation laws and open questions of classical electrodynamics*](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/1045) by Marijan Ribarič and Luka Šušteršič (World Scientific, 1990) discusses this problem, but it's a good place to look.